# Facebook Messenger Bot - View Greeting Text

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm developing a bot for FB Messenger and want to set a greeting text for the first time a user interacts with the bot.

I followed what the docs say on setting the [greeting text](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/messenger-profile/greeting-text). Now I would like to test it and view the greeting message. However, I am stuck because I have already sent the bot messages and hence am not able to view the bot as a new user.

How is it possible to viewing the greeting message UI as if you were a new user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no "official" way to see the greeting message UI as if you were a new user.

But, a workaround for this is to **delete the conversation** (from your messenger application or from Facebook's chat) **and reinitiate it.**